# Custom Widgets without tons of boilerplate?

Tags: flutter, dart

is it possible to create a custom widget that exposes all the original widget arguments without writing tons of boilerplate
This is example just adds the word "Hello" to the beginning of a Text Widget and there is TONS of code!
Is there a code generator that could do this automatically?
What do guys think is best practice?

```dart
class HelloText extends Text {
  final String? data;
  final InlineSpan? textSpan;
  final TextStyle? style;
  final StrutStyle? strutStyle;
  final TextAlign? textAlign;
  final TextDirection? textDirection;
  final Locale? locale;
  final bool? softWrap;
  final TextOverflow? overflow;
  final double? textScaleFactor;
  final int? maxLines;
  final String? semanticsLabel;
  final TextWidthBasis? textWidthBasis;
  final TextHeightBehavior? textHeightBehavior;
  final Color? selectionColor;

  const HelloText(String this.data,
      {super.key, \\ Boiler
      this.style,
      this.strutStyle,
      this.textAlign,
      this.textDirection,
      this.locale,
      this.softWrap,
      this.overflow,
      this.textScaleFactor,
      this.maxLines,
      this.semanticsLabel,
      this.textWidthBasis,
      this.textHeightBehavior,
      this.selectionColor,
      this.textSpan,
      })
      : super(
          "Hello" + data,
          style: style,
          strutStyle: strutStyle,
          textAlign: textAlign,
          textDirection: textDirection,
          locale: locale,
          softWrap: softWrap,
          overflow: overflow,
          textScaleFactor: textScaleFactor,
          maxLines: maxLines,
          semanticsLabel: semanticsLabel,
          textWidthBasis: textWidthBasis,
          textHeightBehavior: textHeightBehavior,
          selectionColor: selectionColor,
        );
}
```

I thought a code generator for this would exist.

Comment: Composition, not inheritance.  If you write code with inheritance, and a new parameter gets added, your code is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Dart 2.17, you can use [super initializers](https://dart.dev/language/constructors#super-parameters). This allows you to avoid having to some parameters when you call the `super` constructor just as you did with your `key` parameter. This is as simple as it will get, about a 1/3 the length of what you originally wrote:

```dart
class HelloText extends Text {
  const HelloText(
    String data, {
    super.key,
    super.style,
    super.strutStyle,
    super.textAlign,
    super.textDirection,
    super.locale,
    super.softWrap,
    super.overflow,
    super.textScaleFactor,
    super.maxLines,
    super.semanticsLabel,
    super.textWidthBasis,
    super.textHeightBehavior,
    super.selectionColor,
  }) : super("Hello $data");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was just looking at the other factory methods and realized this would be the best way to do it.